# Oracle APEX bi dimensional table with changing number of values

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a table of projects and a table of products and I have a third linking table mentioning for each project which products are included in it.
Is there a way to create a bi dimensional table in Oracle Apex that would show in the columns the list of products and in the rows the list of projects and each cell will indicate whether the project includes that product?

I need this to be dynamic enough so that if a product/project is added to the system, I won't need to do any code changes for it.

In addition, I need the cells of this table to be clickable in a way that they would lead to a relevant page/form for updating details.

P.S. I'm asking this question because AFAIK APEX wants to have the list of columns in advance, and it allows setting the attributes for each. If this is not the case, how would I be setting the configuration of each column, when the number of columns is unknown?

Thank you

Comment: You could create a template table with, say 50 columns and then control header and visibility using a single page item per column. Dynamically build your query and fill remaining columns with nulls.

Comment: Thank you @KoenLostrie. Much appreciated